# Issues making import in python

Tags: python

I'm new with python and I'm trying to import one module for using some functions but I'm having issues with it.
This is my directory:

[image]

This is my source path:

```
/home/adrian/eclipse-workspace/Desarrollos/desarollos_backend_HLC_filters/website_base_filter_2/controllers/generic_functions.py
```

This is my class inside the file.

```
class CustomerPortalFilters(CustomerPortal):

    def hola(self):
        print('que pasa')
```

From the module website_invoice_filter_2 I need to import the file **generic_functions.py** from website_base_filter_2.

This is my try, but Eclipse IDE cannot resolve it.

```
from Desarrollos.desarollos_backend_HLC_filters.website_base_filter_2.controllers.generic_functions import CustomerPortalFilters
```

[image]

Thanks for reading.

Comment: There need to be an `__init__.py` in all directories all the way down to the file you want to import. Could you try to add one in each directory and try again?

Comment: Created the file but I'm not able to make the impòrt structure correctly. @HampusLarsson

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `__init__.py` at the root level in order to use it in the import.

Just create a new empty file named `__init__.py` and try again. Basically it will tell the interpreter that it is a python directory so that you can use it in other python files.

Comment: Created the file but I'm not able to make the import structure navigating into folders. @Jay Patel

Comment: Can you try by giving relative path, like `../website_base_filter_2.controllers.generic_functions`

Comment: In the __init__.py file or in the website_base_filter file? @Jay Patel

Comment: In the file where you're trying to import that module

Comment: In the file website_invoice_filters_2/controllers/invoices.py. In the directory structure is in the same level as website_base_filter_2 @Jay Patel